# Jquery DatePicker color Sunday red

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

Is there a way to change the color to, say red, the Sundays in a Jquery Datepicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Sundays and Saturdays you can consider using fact that jquery datepicker adds class `.ui-datepicker-week-end` so you can add `.ui-datepicker-week-end{color:#f00;}` to you css file.

If you want to handle only Sundays you must relay on fact that this will be either first or last column in a table generated by jquery datepicker (it is locale-dependent).

General advice: use firefox+firebug(or sth similiar) to inspect html code. it gives a lot of ideas how to accomplish tasks related to jquery DOM traversing.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#something').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay:function(date){
        if(date.toString().indexOf('Sun ')!=-1)
            return [1,'red'];else
            return [1];
    }
}
```

css:

```
.ui-datepicker td.red a{
color:#f00 !important;
}
```

Not very beautiful, but works as needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a local copy of the ui.datepicker.js file (the custom minified file would work too) and are doing nothing else with the .ui-datepicker-week-end class, you can edit it (making a copy to edit is preferred,) so that only Sunday is assigned that class.

In the ui.datepicker.js file, searching for 'week-end' should bring up two results with this inline if statement preceding them: `(t+h+6)%7>=5?`  Changing the >=5 to ==6 will assign the .ui-datepicker-week-end class only to Sundays then.

```
(t+h+6)%7==6?" ui-datepicker-week-end":""
```

Then you can add CSS styling as you see fit to that class:

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end {
    background: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the first column is sunday then the following jQuery should do the trick:

```
$('table.ui-datepicker-calendar td.ui-datepicker-week-end:nth-child(1) a').css({'background':'#f00'});
```

Though it would have to be run each time the calendar is changed e.g. when you select a date as the calendar is redrawn every time.

You could use the same selector in css3 though it is not supported in IE.

```
table.ui-datepicker-calendar td.ui-datepicker-week-end:nth-child(1) a
{
    background: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to color both Saturday and Sunday use this CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end, .ui-datepicker-week-end a.ui-state-default {color: #C00;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the Theming tab on the [documentation page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), you can see the example HTML output by the plugin.  You should be able to use selectors to target specific elements in the HTML:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody td:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody td:first-child").css("background-color: red");
```

Untested and assumes the first column is Sunday, so a bit of tweaking might be required.  If Sunday is set to a different column, use `:nth-child(n)` instead.

Comment: good example, but sometimes Sunday is the last column (eg. Polish localization) but the change is quite easy to do I think

Comment: @Dzida: it is configurable and can be any column in the table, in this case, you could use `:nth-child(n)` or `:last-child`.  Edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

you can change color sunday using css

```
.datepicker table tr td:first-child {
 color: red
 }
```

saturday color can change like this

```
.datepicker table tr td:first-child + td + td + td + td + td + td  {
 color: red
 }
```

if not working this your code,go to inspent element and find correct css path for datepicker date and set above css ot it