# Primefaces calendar, apply custom style for weekends and holidays

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I want to apply css for weekends and holidays for p:calendar. I am trying to invoke the 
`beforeShowDay` event using jQuery and based on condition set the css.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", function (date) {
          //If condition true
          return [true,'holidays'];
          //else
          return [true,''];
       });
    });     
</script>

<style>
    .holidays {background-color: wheat;}
</style>

<h:form prependId="false">
      <p:calendar/>
</h:form>
```

But the event is not getting fired. Is there anything else I am missing, or any other approach?

Comment: does this 1 works better ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7112923/617373

Comment: $('#something').datepicker({ beforeShowDay:function(date){......} requires id of the component, I want to invoke same script for all calender components in my application.

Comment: just do use class selector , like this `$('.hasDatepicker').datepicker({ beforeShowDay:function(date){......}`

Comment: tried but no luck....                                             $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.hasDatepicker').datepicker({ 
 beforeShowDay:function(date){
     alert('hi');
  }
 });
});

Answer (score 5):

You should use `beforeShowDay` attribute

> beforeShowDay : Callback to execute before displaying a date, used to
>   customize date display.
>
> Use beforeShowDay javascript callback to customize the look of each date. The function returns an
>   array with two values, first one is flag to indicate if date would be displayed as enabled and second
>   parameter is the optional style class to add to date cell. Following example disabled tuesdays and
>   fridays. (PrimeFaces Userʼs Guide page 50)

```
<p:calendar value="#{dateBean.date}" beforeShowDay="tuesdaysAndFridaysDisabled" />


function tuesdaysAndFridaysDisabled(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 2 && day != 5), '']
}
```

---

**jQuery Solution**

If you want to solve it without modifying your primefaces element , but using the jquery datepicker `beforeShowDay` attribute take a look at this tutorial [Primefaces calendar – highlight dates](http://bluefoot.info/howtos/primefaces-calendar-highlight-dates/)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your answers, but my idea is adding the above mentioned script in the header layout of my application, which will be invoked for all the calender components for all pages without specifying the 'beforeShowDay' attribute.

Comment: place your js code in some js file , include it in your header and add to all your calendars the `beforeShowDay="myJsFuncFromMyJsFile"` , you will write the code just once and reuse it in all your calendars , this approach is much better than workarounds... also , take a look at the link I posted you will find the workaround that you interested at

Comment: Ya Daniel, it is good approach, but my application has 100's of pages which are already built and tested, So I can't change each and every calender component for this functionality.

Comment: INMO it safer to use a built in functionality instead of workarounds that might stop working after future upgrade.