# Apply custom css on some dates of <p:calendar>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

In my application I have a `<p:calendar>` I want to add custom css(red background) for list of days in a month/year. Suppose now `<p:calendar>` displays october month.
in this month I want to apply css on (2nd October, 10th October) these dates are coming from database.How can I implement this. Any link,advice is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392947/primefaces-calendar-apply-custom-style-for-weekends-and-holidays

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script , it changes event's color depend on a String or a number

```
<style type="text/css"> 


.AnyString .fc-event-skin {
   background: red;
     </style>

</style>
```

And the function is

```
public String getNum(int Num) {
        if(Num==1)
            return"AnyString";
```